# Adb doesn't see my htc device

Tags: android, adb

I tried million of times to reinstall install switch on/off device and still `adb devices` shows empty list. I am sure I have got debugging USB turned on, unknown sources turned on but still nothing. Drivers installed well, I have access to files on phone. Maybe it have something to do with type of connection? I have 4 types: charing, htc sync, as flashdrive, as modem. Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: What operating system, and if Windows, what does the device appear as in Device Manager?

Comment: And do remember to download HTC sense, it works for me after installed.

Answer (score 1):

> I have access to files on phone.

You have to disable "mass storage mode" and choose "charge only" on the device when you connect it.

Answer (score 0):

Close eclipse and try killing the adb process in your task manager.  Relaunch eclipse and it'll automatically restart adb.  This happens to me every once in a while too.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest HTC update, you have no more option for "mass storage mode" or "charge only".
(After updating both phone Sense OS and desktop USB/HTC drivers).

I have to rename C:\Program Files\HTC\HTC Sync Manager\HTC Sync\adb.exe because it cause a conflict with the Android SDK adb.exe

But it work on my HTC One S today :)